# Provisining Profile error whatchkit

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, watchkit, apple-watch

Here is my error

I add 2app ID  bundle for in  Extension and  watchkitapp  after i create 2 Distributions for 2 ID after  i double clicked on 2  Distributions  and i added in Build Settings  -> Watchkit Extension -> Code Signing Identity i good added

Distributions  but when i want to send with Apploader i recived this error

Provisioning profile does not match bundle identifier: The provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“Appnamewatchkitextenstion”) has an AppID of “watchkitextension” which does not match your bundle identifier “Appname.watchkitextension”.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'WatchKit Extension' in SDK 'iOS 8.2'

Alert The  provisioning profile specified in your build setting (App Extension Distributions) has an App ID of "Watchkitextension" witch does not match your build identifier "Appname.watchkitextension "

but if i try to stay in auto provisining profile i ricived this error

Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning Profile included in the bundle Appname.watchkitapp [Appname.app/PlugIns.Appname Watchkit Extension.appex/Appname Watchkit App.app] is invalid.
[Missing code-signing cerfificate.]

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this? I'm having the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom of https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/ says

> Please Note: Apps built with Xcode 6.2 and iOS 8.2 SDK may be
>   submitted to the App Store. However, WatchKit extensions are not
>   accepted at this time.

Comment: Answer is not valid anymore.

Comment: That is correct, you can now submit Apps with WatchKit extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here: [CodeSign error - code signing is required for product type WatchKit App in SDK 8_2](https://mkswap.net/m/blog/CodeSign+error+-+code+signing+is+required+for+product+type+WatchKit+App+in+SDK+8_2)

There's a bug in Xcode 6.2 which requires you to either use Xcode 6.1.1 and set up the correct Code Signing Identity for the WatchKit App, or adjust the Code Signing Identity on the project level in Xcode 6.2. Same goes for Code Signing errors with the WatchKit Extension.